# Ruby on Rails, sum of an attribute of an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having some problems with my Ruby on Rails website. Let me explain.
I have a user model, it has many credits

In order to count, the credits for a user I do:

```
@user.credits.sum(:score)
```

This works fine.

Now have a model team, that has many users, and I want to find out the total number of credits, I found on another StackOverflow post this:

```
array.inject{|sum,x| sum + x }
```

So I thought for me it should look like that:

```
@team.users.inject{|sum,x| sum + x.credits.sum(:score)}
```

But this returns

```
#<User:0x00000101a7c180>
```

instead of the sum. Guess I'm doing something wrong. Don't hesitate if you have an idea.

Thanks

Comment: you are missing a closing curly bracket while collecting score for a team

Comment: thanks, just didn't copy the curly brace for the post

Comment: try @team.users.sum{|i| i.credits.sum(:score)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the initial value:

```
@team.users.inject(0){ |sum,x| sum + x.credits.sum(:score) }
```

You could also do:

```
@team.users.sum{ |x| x.credits.sum(:score) }
```